# Adobe Flash Professional CS5.5 AIR SDK 4

Tags: flash, air, flash-cs5.5

I need to compile my Flash app using AIR 4. I downloaded latest version of AIR SDK [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html) and overwrote the existing SDK like described [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/enable-the-latest-air-sdk-in-flash-professional-cs55--active-11488)

(one difference is player version - I set 23 instead of 15), but during publishing I'm getting errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"__ZN7avmplus15Context3DObject11get_profileEv", referenced from: __ZN7avmplus8NativeID43flash_display3D_Context3D_profile_get_thunkEPNS_9MethodEnvEjPi in AOTBuildOutput-0.o
__ZZ41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0iiE6C.6592 in AOTBuildOutput-0.o
(...)
```

I was searching in Google, but any results. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I tried to compile on another machine (AMD not Intel) and it works perfectly.